# Wet iPhone 4 doesn't know its IMEI and ICCID and displays connect to iTunes but lacks passcode

Tags: itunes, iphone

Well, due to a bit of an accident, my iPhone 4 got wet. The bright side is that it seems to not have suffered CPU damage, since it still boots up fine. The downside? It displays the connect to iTunes screen, and doesn't know its IMEI and ICCID when the information icon is selected. Naturally, I connect the phone to iTunes, since that's what it wants. Unfortunately...

> iTunes could not connect to the iPhone "iPhone" because it is locked with a passcode. You must enter the passcode on the iPhone before it can be used with iTunes.

And naturally, there's no place to enter the passcode on the iPhone, as it continues to display the connect to iTunes screen. Now I suppose I could take it in to Apple, and they'd probably give me a replacement if I'm lucky (I hear water damage isn't covered), but I'd prefer to get this phone working again, since I haven't backed its photos and contacts up before. (I do know it still has those before when I go to the emergency call screen, it does display my normal photo background as the background). So any help?

Comment: Have you tried putting it into dfu mode first?

Comment: @eliben No, does that delete the data on the phone? If not, I'd be willing to give it a go.

Comment: it does erase your data. it puts iphone in "restore mode." so you can restore without passcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautiful for you, Apple just changed their water damage policy to be covered under warranty! If possible, take it to an Apple Store and have them look at it. They can probably fix it if you think that you can, and then you can back it up before getting a replacement. Win Win.

Answer (score 2):

I dropped mine into water shortly after buying it and I saw some weird behaviour too.  I figured that it was submerged for such a short time, less than a second, that not much water would have penetrated the case so that maybe the weird behaviour was down to some shorting that was happening in the dock connector and the headphone socket so I made sure these were clean and entirely dry.  I plugged a dock connector in and out lots of times and after a day or so the weird behaviour stopped.  You can also try putting the phone into a bag of rice which will dry out any residual moisture.  You could wrap it lightly in tissue paper to prevent any small pieces of rice from entering the body of the phone.

Comment: +1 for the bag of rice.  I've heard this perform miracles on all sorts of consumer electronics.